# Not able to upload image in admin-end by Insert Image button

Tags: image, cms, media, image-upload

I am not able to upload images in the admin-end by clicking "Insert Image" link in CMS block or CMS page.

On Clicking Insert Image link the Media gallery popup appears. Then on clicking the browse button it allows me to select image from my machine, but after selecting the image, it throws the error in console and doesn't show me the image in Media gallery popup to upload the image in Magento.

I am getting below error message in the firebug console.

```
<admin-end url>/cms_wysiwyg_images/thumbnail/file/QWJvdXRfUGV0RG9vcnMuY29tX2ltYWdlX29mX2JvcmRlcl9jb2xsaWVfYW5kX2dvbGRlbl9yZXRyaWV2ZXJfZ29pbmdfdGhyb3VnaF9kb2dneV9kb29yXzEucG5n/
```

When I am trying to open this link directly in the browser, it is generating error report.
The error in error report is below :

```
"Unsupported image format.";i:1;s:1512:"#0 lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(60): Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2->_getCallback('create')
```

Same thing is working absolutely fine in my staging environment but creating issue on live.
Staging and live site are on same server.
I have tried uploading different image types as well like gif, png, jpg, but everytime the issue is same. 

What can be the probable cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: could be php version issue on live server or any lib

Comment: @liyakat : My staging and live site are on same server.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966668/cannot-add-image-through-magento-cms-wysiwyg-editor someone had the same problem.

Comment: @kuba_ceg : Thanks, I have already tried this solution, but it is not working for me.

Comment: @AnshuMishra, have you checked php version and gd lib version ?

Comment: @liyakat PHP version is 5.3.24 and GD version is 2.0.34

Comment: Have you checked your logs for possible errors? system.log, exception.log or /var/report?

Comment: @mkerstner : Yes, there is an error in error report, that I had already shared in my question.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Then please double-check your PHP setup, i.e. extension versions as stated before. Even if your systems are on the same server you can still setup PHP differently through php.ini for instance. Also, compare your phpinfo() output for both projects. Also, check your permissions.

Comment: I have compared the .htaccess and there is php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 2048 on staging but same is not on live. What this line means? Can this cause any problem?

Comment: "suhosin.get.max_value_length" defines the maximum length of a variable that is registered through the URL. It is safe to implement increase it without causing any problems.

Comment: That should not be the problem at hand. What about phpinfo()?

Comment: @mkerstner : Result of phpinfo() is same for live and staging. Please let me know if I need to look for any particular thing in phpinfo().

Comment: Does your user have sufficient write permissions? Have you tried different images?

Comment: @mkerstner I have checked and file permissions are fine.

Comment: The issue seems to be CDN related, for testing I have removed SSL cdn url and changed to default Magento url and now it is working. But now the point is why it is not working with SSL CDN url and how I can fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento backend can't upload images when media is on cdn](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/magento-backend-cant-upload-images-when-media-is-on-cdn)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was related to CDN.
My full store is on secure and working with CDN.

Some elements of the image uploader and the wysiwyg content editor are served from within your ‘skin’ directory – which is now served from your CDN, and will start throwing cross domain errors.

The Secure and Unsecure URL settings configured in the default config (top left) in the admin section. Are global – they affect all the stores and the admin area. In order to disable the CDN on the admin, but keep it for the website, change the scope of your configuration to Main Website (top left), uncheck the ‘Use Default’ settings, and then add in the CDN urls.

 
So under Current Configuration Scope: Default config you should use ;

http://www.yourdomain.com/

Under Current Configuration Scope: Main Website and default store view you should use

http://cname.yourdomain.com/ I’ve created Cname records to map to the cdn url’s (it’s neater) but you can just use the cdn urls if you prefer.

Some reference links :

- [magento backend can't upload images when media is on cdn](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/magento-backend-cant-upload-images-when-media-is-on-cdn)
- http://www.citricmedia.co.uk/magento-cdn/cant-upload-images-or-use-the-wysiwyg-editor-with-full-functionality-after-creating-cdn/

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your magento cache and flush everything

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85489)

Comment: Well it worked for me and the symptoms were exactly the same. It does provide an answer, the correct one. If you look at the other answer a emphasis on CDN is made but the question does not mention CDN once.