# Magento 1.8.1.0 WYSIWYG editor: have not Browses File and Upload Files button

Tags: magento-1.8, wysiwyg, file-upload

When i insert an image to CMS Block Static, i can not upload new file. The Browses File and Upload Files button does not appear.
Can everyone help me?

Thanks.
 [image]

Comment: This can be caused by few issues:

1. Missing media/wysiwyg directory.
2. Wrong permissions on media/wysiwyg directory.
3. Https issue see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61593/13907 / http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7556/13907

Please check up your browser's console, Magento log and server log for any error. Reply in comment and I'll try to respond with answer accordingly.

Comment: It can also be realted to your browser not supporting flash any more. At least Chrome stopped Flash support already. Maybe try another browser or enable Flash manually

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am getting same error.
Getting an error in console:
prototype.js:612 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:612
(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:865
(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:825
each @ prototype.js:824
collect @ prototype.js:864
evalScripts @ prototype.js:612
(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:391
(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:416

Comment: same here. any insights on this in the meantime?